# Instantiating COM object hnetcfg.fwpolicy2 on Remote Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I locked my self out by inadvertently changing RDP firewall rule to use IPSec,but without completing proper steps to setup IPSec channel from my laptop to server.

Luckily all wmi remoting on Server works,So I am trying to edit the rule with Powershell

When I enter below code ,the COM object is invoking on local machine.How can I invoke it on remote machine?

```
Enter-PSSession $Session
$fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more digging around web and and found that to activate remote com object via remoting  we need to use

```
$fw = [Activator]::CreateInstance([Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID([Guid]"{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}",$ServerName))
```

Unfortunately, in my case this didn't work either as it need remote activation of COM objects to be enabled on server,which I didn't.

However ,I changed tracks and used Invoke Command to ship the code for local execution on server and  managed to fix it as mentioned in this link.

https://gist.github.com/2181246